# Restoring from Glacier after Synology NAS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nas, synology, amazon-glacier

Have been using Synology NAS for backup for quite some time.

Due to changes in structure will be migrating to new system and need to restore all files from Glacier.

Tried using CloudBerry Backup (desktop free) however after synchronizing there where no listed files for restoration.

Also tried using Fast Glacier, however this resulted in errors preventing the backup from functioning.

Any and all suggestions more than welcome.

Comment: Can you provide more information? For example, it sounds like you are saying that your Synology NAS was automatically backing up to Glacier? How was this initially configured? Can you see any vaults/archives in Glacier? What errors did you receive? If you can provide more information, we will better be able to offer suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Is S3 involved in this configuration?  I suspect so, and If so, that's significant.  Note also that you need to be sure you understand glacier restoration pricing. Making the wrong move can be costly.

Comment: For Synology and Glacier, my impression (unless they've updated the application), is that it will restore to only another Synology device.  Because of this reason, my impression at the time was that it really limits the utility of using the Glacier app (since backups won't be helpful if the Synology device is destroyed or stolen which is the main reason for using the backup application in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

The most easy approach would be if you could copy the files in question from your Synology NAS to the new system, whether it is a new Synology NAS or something else. It is the fastest and most cost-efficient way.

If you migrating to the new Synology, you should just copy the files from the old one. If it is somehow not possible, you should use "Retrieve task" button from "Restore" tab.

[image: Screenshot]

Beware, it will take long time just to retrieve the task. When retrieving the task, Synology NAS will download files related to the task. These files contain all the information about your backup task: which files are backed up, versions, file location, size and so on. When the task is retrieved, you can begin to recover the files. Use this [calculator](http://liangzan.net/aws-glacier-calculator/) to calculate the restore price before you begin - it is far from cheap. 
Also, hope that restore will succeed (because, sometimes, backup integrity fails which makes restore not possible)

In case you restore to some other system than Synology, you should definitely copy the files from your old Synology. If you no longer have access to the old Synology NAS, buy a new Synology (or maybe use XPenology), restore to it and then copy the files to the new system. Amazon Glacier on Synology NAS backs up in proprietary format, which to my knowledge only readable by other Synology devices.

Good luck with migration.